# How do string comparison operators work in Twig?

Tags: php, twig

How is this possible? It seems to be a very very odd issue (unless I’m missing something very simple):

Code:

```php
{{ dump(nav) }}
{% if nav == "top" %}
    <div class="well">This would be the nav</div>
{% endif %}
```

Output:

```html
boolean true
<div class="well">This would be the nav</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Basically, it is outputting if true, but it’s not meant to be checking for true.

Comment: Sorry, figured it would not make a difference with only 4 lines of code.

Comment: Questions you post on here should always be selfcontained. Once the links die your question is useless to future readers.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is easily reproductible :

```
{% set nav = true %}
{% if nav == "top" %}
ok
{% endif %}
```

Displays `ok`.

According to the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html) :

> Twig allows expressions everywhere. These work **very similar** to regular
>   PHP and even if you're not working with PHP you should feel
>   comfortable with it.

And if you test in pure PHP the following expression :

```
$var = true;
if ($var == "top") {
  echo 'ok';
}
```

It will also display ok.

The point is : you should not compare variables of different types. Here, you compare a bool with a string : if your string is not empty or if it does not contains only zeros, it will evaluate to true.

You can also have a look to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to see how comparison are made with different types.

### Edit

You can use the [sameas](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/sameas.html) test to make strict comparisions, and avoid type juggling matters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not actually using the code like this, but i stumbled across it while i was changing things from "display_nav" to allow a position to be specified. I was not sure if it was a bug, or if i was just missing something. Thank you for your detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs to negate result of the string comparison statement use next construction:

```twig
{% set is_training = course_type == 'training' %}
...
{% if not is_training %}
...
```